# Custom Histogram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, histogram

I am trying to create the picture below in Tikz. What I am most unsure of is how to make the histogram below. It does not need to have the exact same shape, but a similar shape to the histogram below. Unfortunately I don't have the underlying dataset. What is the best way to make this in Tikz?

[image]

Comment: You can produce such things easily with `pgplots` by adding two axis on top of each other with one being an `ybar` plot and the other an ordinary plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=18cm,height=7cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \begin{axis}[ybar,bar width=2.7mm,ylabel={Number of policies},yticklabel=$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$,
 xticklabel=$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$,xlabel={Score based on \dots}]
  \addplot[samples=50,domain=0:100,fill=yellow!20] {25*x*x*x*exp(-x/10)*(0.9+0.2*rnd)};
 \end{axis}
 \begin{axis}[axis y line=right,ylabel={Actual loss ratio},xtick=\empty,ymax=200,ymin=0,
 yticklabel=$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}\,\%$]
  \addplot[samples=50,domain=0:100] {180-1.6*x+20*(rnd-0.5)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!